# Identify figure with barely any print left on its torso

Tags: clone-brands, minifigure-identification

I really appreciate the effort

[image]

Comment: The shape of the torso as well as horrible quality of legs means this minifig is not LEGO. And with its print almost missing it will be nearly impossible to identify.

Comment: Hi David and welcome to Bricks.SE! Can you please add some more details to your question? For example, where did you get this figure, does it have a LEGO logo anywhere, does it have the same dimensions as genuine LEGO minifigures? Then take the time to read the [help] and [tour] pages to learn how this community operates and be sure to respond to comments and answers. Have fun!

Comment: It looks like suspenders to my uninformed eye, but no google image searches yielded any joy. I could also believe it's the back of coveralls, but I had similar results.

Comment: Thanks for helping me!
The figure is LEGO sized. My kid fell in love with it on his kindergarten and bagged me to find it for him and maybe try and buy one...
I don't have any other details but from Alex's comment it is now clear that it is not an original LEGO figure (the curves of the torso are definitely not LEGOs).